# Visualising multiple tables in Pandas on Notebook

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, visualization

I have 4 panda dataframes in a Google Colab notebook. I would like to create an interactive table that has a dropdown menu that lets me choose which of the 4 tables to view.
I am aware of [iTables](https://github.com/mwouts/itables) and the colab google.colab.data_table extension that let you have interactive tables in the notebook. I didn't see one that lets me load 4 different ones at once with a dropdown menu to pick which one to view. I was wondering if anyone knew of such an extension/feature.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Colab's form to make a dropdown with autorun.

```py
#@title {run: 'auto'}
df_name = "df2" #@param ["df1", "df2", "df3", "df4"]
df = globals()[df_name]
df
```

Here's a runnable [colab example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ufxd1A7BlV8wQJ4RPNqw03exCknmA37k?usp=sharing).